# CSS/PHP Fill Screen with divs

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to fill the screen with divs, and I'm thinking about using php to dynamically resize the divs based on the screen resoultion, so, for example, 16 divs always appear in each row.

[image: Example of DIV spacing]

Example A is the problem, in Example B I resize the divs to fit the screen.

So, is this efficient? I would have something like this for each background image of each div:

```
/bgimage.php?id=123456&resize=125
```

Where resize is calculated by dividing the browser width by 16, or the # of divs I want in each row.

I'm not sure about using this method, because I don't want the divs to appear to small if the resolution is very low.

Any other suggestions? Could this be done better using just CSS or javascript?
The

Comment: CSS/JavaScript would definitely give you immediate results. PHP will require a round-trip visit to the server each time you resize the browser.

Comment: PHP is server-side, not client side. PHP will never know screen resolution, I think you're looking for CSS/javascript's onresize event in this scenario.

Comment: firstly: php does not have access to client screensize's & this can be done with css alone

Comment: Use CSS and percentages for the width value.

Comment: Its better to work with JS and CSS. PHP rocks on the server.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/445157/alex have a look at the OP's profile. 5 questions, and none accepted. All questions answered to its best. :D. Bye Alex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see why you need any scripting in any language?

If you set every div to float left with a width of 6% then 16 divs will take up 96% of the width no matter what the screen is resized to. You can wrap them in another div with a 4% margin to handle the remaining 4%.

Comment: But I would still need to resize the background images

Comment: @Alex In css3 there is a property called `background-size` you can also set to a percentage. So if each div has `background-size:100%`  than no matter their size, the background will fit. Won't work on older browsers though.

Comment: However, IE6 doesn't interpret margins and paddings correctly, so you have to account for that when you code your CSS.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in CSS alone. Simply set the width of the div to 6.25% (100/16), and then set a min-width for that smallest possible width.

http://jsbin.com/ozuxa4

Comment: The background images are a fixed size, so I would need to resize them.

Comment: If you set a percentage for the image width/height they will automatically resize when screen gets resized.  You just need to set it as a percentage rather than a specific number.